# C# imitate The Windows Notification Panel Functionality

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm Creating a Windows forms Program for My Graduating Project.
And The Thing is I want to implement something similar to that of showing cards when an event is called and the user can clear them.

Comment: Any reason you need to reinvent the wheel and not use the standard OS notification? Also, search NuGet for notifications. There's a whole bunch of custom ones there.

Comment: Just to have the application to have it's own notfication system... And don't use the MessageBox

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.